# How to use DINO as a feature extractor?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I'd like to use [DINO github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino) as a feature extractor. But I don't know how to instantiate a DINO model and then feed it a set of images (like cifar10) and save features?

Basically, how to load a model and then from the checkpoints visulize a features (with no traning-- just the checkpoints)?

Answer (score 2):

You need PyTorch installed. Then you just use the model you want (which will be downloaded upon first use) as shown in github. For example, for vits16:

```
vits16 = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/dino:main', 'dino_vits16')
features = vits16(your_input)
```

You can then do what you want with the features.

Comment: Hi @DMcC thank you very much! how do you lnow what checkpoints is loaded in `vits16` that you have instantiated? In the repo there are plenty ot checkpoint. if one wants to load special one, is it possible?

Comment: The checkpoints are described in the [readme of the project repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino/blob/main/README.md#pretrained-models-on-pytorch-hub). With `torch.hub.load` you not only load the model's architecture but also the checkpoint weights.

Answer (score 1):

- Import packages

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms as pth_transforms
from PIL import Image
```

- Load model

```
model_dino = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/dino:main', 'dino_vits16', pretrained=True)

model_dino.eval()

#if GPU is available
device = torch.device("cuda")
model_dino.to(device)
```

you can choose from [several Dino variants](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino#pretrained-models-on-pytorch-hub)

- Define model transforms

```
transform = pth_transforms.Compose([
        pth_transforms.ToTensor(),
        pth_transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),
    ])
```

based on [source](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino/blob/7c446df5b9f45747937fb0d72314eb9f7b66930a/eval_image_retrieval.py#L106)

- Load image and transform image

```
img = Image.open(image_path)
img_tensor = transform(img)
```

- Predict image

```
img_tensor = img_tensor.unsqueeze(0).cuda()
predictions = model_dino(img_tensor)
```